# Detecting invalid (Windows) filenames

Tags: windows, powershell, filesystems

We have SMB shares that are used by Windows and Mac clients. We want to move some data to Sharepoint, but need to validate the filenames against characters that are not allowed in Windows. Although Windows users wouldn't be able to create files with illegal characters anyway, Mac users are still able to create files with characters that are illegal in Windows.

The problem is that for files with illegal characters in their names, Windows/Powershell substitutes those characters with private-use address unicode codepoint. These vary by input character.

```
$testfolder = "\\server\test\test*dir"   # created from a Mac
$item = get-item -path $testfolder
$item.Name                               # testdir
$char = $($item.Name)[4]                 # 
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes($char) # 240:33
$unicode = [System.BitConverter]::toString($bytes)                # F0-21
```

For a file with name `pipe|`, the above code produces the output `F0-27`, so it's not simply a generic "invalid" character.

How can I check filenames for invalid values when I can't actually get the values??

Comment: The files should be identifiable by running PowerShell on MacOS. https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell

Comment: True, and that's definitely a viable solution. But I'm stubborn and wanted to find a solution that doesn't require me to switch platforms just to run a script. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 4):

As often happens, in trying to formulate my question as precisely as possible, I came upon a solution. I would still love any other answers for how this could be tackled more elegantly, but since I didn't find any other resources with this information, I'm providing my solution here in hopes it might help others with this same problem.

## Invalid Characters Map to Specific Codepoints

*Note: I'm extrapolating all of this from observations I've made. I'm happy for someone to comment or provide an alternative answer that is more complete or correct.*

There is a certain set of characters that are invalid for Windows file names, but this is a restriction of the OS, NOT the filesystem. This means that that it's possible to set a filename on an SMB share that is valid on another OS (e.g. MacOS) but not on Windows. When Windows encounters such a file, the invalid characters are shadowed by a set of proxy unicode codepoints, which allows Windows to interact with the files without renaming them. These codepoints are in the unicode Private Use Area, which covers `0xE000-0xF8FF`. Since these codepoints are not mapped to printable characters, Powershell displays them all as ▯ (`U+25AF`). In my specific use case, I need to run a report of what invalid characters are present in a filename, so this generic character message is not helpful.

Through experimentation, I was able to determine the proxy codepoints for each of the printable restricted characters. I've included them below for reference (*note: YMMV on this, I haven't tested it on multiple systems, but I suspect it's consistent between versions*).

| Character | Unicode |
| --- | --- |
| " | 0xF020 |
| * | 0xF021 |
| / | 0xF022 |
| < | 0xF023 |
| > | 0xF024 |
| ? | 0xF025 |
| \ | 0xF026 |
| | | 0xF027 |
| (trailing space) | 0xF028 |

`:` is not allowed in filenames on any system I have easy access to, so I wasn't able to test that one.

## Testing names in Powershell

Now that we know this, it's pretty simple to tackle in powershell. I created a hashtable with all of the proxy unicode points as keys and the "real" characters as values, which we can then use as a lookup table. I chose to replace the characters in the filename string before testing the name. This makes debugging easier.

```
#Set up regex for invalid characters
$invalid = [Regex]::new('^\s|[\"\*\:<>?\/\\\|]|\s$') 

#Create lookup table for unicode values
$charmap = @{
    [char]0xF020 = '"'
    [char]0xF021 = '*'
    [char]0xF022 = '/'
    [char]0xF023 = '<'
    [char]0xF024 = '>'
    [char]0xF025 = '?'
    [char]0xF026 = '\'
    [char]0xF027 = '|'
    [char]0xF028 = ' '
} 

Get-ChildItem -Path "\\path\to\folder" -Recurse | Foreach-Object {
    # Get the filename 
    $fixedname = split-path -path $_.FullName -leaf

    #Iterate through the hashtable and replace all the proxy characters with printable versions
    foreach($key in $charmap.getEnumerator()){
         $fixedname = $fixedname.Replace($key.Name,$key.Value)
    }
     #Build a list of invalid characters to include in report (not shown here)
     $invalidmatches = $invalid.Matches($fixedname)
     if ($invalidmatches.count -gt 0) {
         $invalidchars = $($invalidmatches | foreach-object {
           if ($_.value -eq ' '){"Leading or trailing space"} else {$_.value}}) -join ", "
     }
}
```

## Extending the solution

In theory, you could also extend this to cover other prohibited characters, such as the ASCII control characters. Since these proxy unicode points are in the PUA, and there is no documentation on how this is handled (as far as I know), discovering these associations is down to experimentation. I'm content to stop here, as I have run through all of the characters that are easily put in filenames by users on MacOS systems.